# Unable to get values from jQuery Dialog in C#?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, c#-4.0

I am using GridView in ASP.Net and add jQuery Dialog to show data on Edit button, it loads Dialog and display's data when I click on Save Button of Dailog, I am unable to get values in ASP.Net (C#) Code Behind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Phone-Modal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 430,
            modal: false,
            open: function (type, data) {
                $("#Phone-Modal").parent().appendTo($("form"));
            }
        });            
    });
    function showDialog(id) {
        $('#' + id).dialog("open");

    }
</script>

<div id="Phone-Modal" class="p10" title="Phone Verifications">
    <div class="left wfull">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"></asp:Label></div>
    <div class="left clear" style="height: 248px">
        <div class="left">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HdfMemberID" runat="server" Value="" />
            Profile : <span style="margin-left: 65px; font-weight: bold">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProfile"></asp:Label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="left clear wfull mt10 mb10">
            Phone Number : <span style="font-weight: bold">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPhone"></asp:Label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="left wfull mt10 mb10">
            <div style="width: 110px; padding-right: 20px;">
                Admin Notes:</div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ReplyTextBox1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Rows="10" Columns="25"
                MaxLength="2000" ValidationGroup="sendEmail" Style="background-color: White;
                width: 100px !important;">
            </asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxtoolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" TargetControlID="ReplyTextBox1"
                runat="server">
                <Toolbar>
                    <ajaxtoolkit:Undo />
                    <%--<ajaxtoolkit:Redo />
                        <ajaxtoolkit:Bold />
                        <ajaxtoolkit:Italic />
                        <ajaxtoolkit:Underline />
                        <ajaxtoolkit:InsertOrderedList />
                        <ajaxtoolkit:Indent />
                        <ajaxtoolkit:Outdent />
                        <ajaxtoolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
                        <ajaxtoolkit:ForeColorSelector />--%>
                </Toolbar>
            </ajaxtoolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="left clear mt140">
            Pass Code:
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassCode1" name="txtPassCode1" TextMode="Password"
                Style="margin-left: 43px;">
            </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfmid" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Member_ID")%>' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left wfull " style="margin-top: 25px">
        <div class="left mt15">
            <label>
                Verify Phone:
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="left mt10">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPhoneStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPhoneStatus_SelectedIndexChanged"
                CssClass="dropdown_effect ml30" Width="175px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select Status" Value="0">
                </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Verified" Value="1">
                </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Not Verified" Value="2">
                </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="mb20" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdHeader" CellPadding="5"
                OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Profile" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                        <ItemStyle Width="130px" HorizontalAlign="center" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hl" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/test.aspx?id={0}","id"))) %>'
                                Target="_blank"><%# Eval("Alias") %></asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone1">
                        <ItemStyle Width="130px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPhone1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value 1")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone Type">
                        <ItemStyle Width="130px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPhone2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value 2")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemStyle Width="200px" CssClass="TxtCenter" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <span style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="OpenDialog" runat="server" CssClass="buttons" OnClientClick="showDialog('Phone-Modal','click'); return false;">Update</asp:LinkButton></span>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                        <ItemStyle Width="0" HorizontalAlign="center" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdfl" Value='<%# Eval("ID")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a id="popup" href='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>Edit</a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

protected void ddlPhoneStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string strTest = lblPhone.Text;
.....
}
```

Simply I am unable to get the values from jQuery dialog to C# when I click on SelectedIndexChanged of DropDownList give on Dialog.

Thank you,
Jahan Zeb

Comment: Please post relavant code ... HTML,JQUERY....

Comment: Yes, dear I have posted codes, thanks you.

Comment: Does it mean that SelectedIndexChanged event of dropdown not firing up? or you're not gettting the value in that event? you also mentioned that you're not able to get data in save button click event. Confused, which is not working?

Comment: Yes, I tried both, SelectedIndexChanged and Button Click events, not getting the value in CodeBehind

Comment: @JahanZeb do you have find some solution for this ? i also have same problem.

Comment: Yes, but I left this technique for taking it further, I am using jQuery AJAX / Web Service solutions for all existing and upcoming modules for my Project, I suggest you too, better you go with this too. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you gave the controls runat="server" property

Comment: Thank you for your kind response, yes, I have checked all srever tags many times.